ElectronJS - Listen for wireless display added in windows
In my electrojs app, I want to listen to an event or use some API to find if there are any displays connected to my windows laptop (via wireless display option).
Below code doesn't get fired on choosing projection mode as "Duplicate" in windows. It gets fired on "Extended Display".
import {screen} from "electron;
app.whenReady()
   .then(() => {
      screen.on("display-added", (e, display) => {
          console.log("added display");
      });

      screen.on("display-removed", (e, display) => {
          console.log("removed display");
          });

      screen.on("display-metrics-changed", (e, display) => {
          console.log("changed display");
      });
})

Windows use Miracast to wirelessly project screens. I have tried listening to events on screen in electron app. But, they are only emitted on extended monitor option.
